# If you have 99 in a skill, and roll a 96, is it a success or a fumble?

Tags: skills, fumbles, call-of-cthulhu-7e

To succeed a roll in Call of Cthulhu you have to meet or roll under your skill threshold, but rolls that are between 96-100 are fumbles (critical failures).

What happens when you roll under your skill threshold (of 99), but within the fumble range as well?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is a success (assuming a regular difficulty check).

From the top of Page 90 of the 7th edition core rulebook:

> If the dice roll required for success is 50 or over and the dice read 100, a fumble has occurred.
>   If the dice roll required for success is below 50 and the dice read 96—100, a fumble has occurred.

Comment: Now I see it! I must have skimmed over it because it was at the very top of the next page.